# ¿Cómo abrir un fichero pdf desde un enlace en un webview?

Tags: android, webview-android

Mi aplicación consiste en un acceso a una web privada que es mostrada en un webview. Hay enlaces dentro de la web que permiten descargar ficheros en formato pdf o en doc, docx. Al hacer tap en el enlace no se ejecuta ninguna acción con ninguno de los dos tipos de fichero.
El método que utilizo para mostrar el webview una vez logueado, es el siguiente:

```
private void showWebView(boolean loginOK)
{
   if (loginOK)
   {
      mWebView.loadUrl(URL_PR);
   }
   else 
   {
      msj(ERROR_LOGIN); 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Me parece que deseas abrir un link dentro de un WebView que contiene el url a un archivo .pdf, agregue una respuesta, la primera opción sería la ideal  mediante un WebViewClient().

Comment: ¿Uhmm? Especifica mas tu pregunta, ¿Mostrando los _PDF'S_ dentro de tu misma app o usando algún lector externo?

Comment: @x4mp73r Quiero mostrar los PDF's, .doc, .docx en el mismo webview.

Answer (score 7):

#### Para abrir un archivo .PDF al dar clic en un link dentro de un WebView, puedes usar el método shouldOverrideUrlLoading() y realizar un intent:

```
WebView  webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //Verifica si es .pdf
        if (url.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))){
            //Crea un Intent para abrir un archivo con MIME TYPE application/pdf 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            try{
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //Error!
            }
        } else {  //Si no es .pdf simplemente carga la url en el WebView.
            webview.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

---

#### Para abrir un archivo .PDF dentro de un `WebView`, como opción puedes usar el visor de Google Drive, este es un ejemplo:

```
     WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    
            }
        });
        
         //Url Ejemplo:
        String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
    
         //Carga url de .PDF en WebView  mediante Google Drive Viewer. 
        webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: la primera opción me muestra los ficheros .pdf en la aplicación que tiene el móvil como predeterminada para abrirlos, gracias. ¿Cómo puedo mostrarlos directamente en el webview?.

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que algunos ficheros no los descarga porque no tienen el nombre del fichero en la url. En estos casos ¿cómo los descargo?.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo mostrarlos directamente en el webview?. mediante Google viewer, la segunda opción. Te refieres a que no tienen extensión? por ejemplo : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/archivo

Comment: En la ruta de descarga, no está el nombre ni la extensión del fichero, por ejemplo: documentos.com/at_download/file

Comment: En esa ruta hay una lista de ficheros que el usuario puede descargar al dar click sobre cada uno de ellos. He intentado con el método setDownloadListener pero el fichero que descarga es un html y no el .pdf o .doc respectivos.

Answer (score 1):

En Android, si quieres abrir un fichero pdf desde una url lo puedes hacer mediante un Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

donde `url` es la `url` en la que se encuentra el pdf.

Comment: ¿En qué momento identifico que el usuario ha hecho tap en ese enlace de la web que muestro en el WebView ?. Puede estar en cualquier página.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado esta solución que al menos me permite descargar el fichero sin que tenga que indicarle el tipo de extensión del fichero a descargar. La primera opción (1. download via webview) del usuario @Cassie
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278292/how-to-download-files-in-webview
Sigo buscando la opción de abrir directamente el fichero en el webview. ¿Alguna idea?.